# MVC on form submit open JQuery dialog and wait for user response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC app; inside the form when user clicks 'Save' button it should submit the form to the controller and save changes. If certain conditions are met, it will pop JQuery UI dialoog, execute some ajax calls asking for user input in the dialog and submit the form after user clicks new 'Save' button inside the dialog.

My problem is that on form 'Save' button click, the dialog comes up but the page gets posted right away (i can see loader working in the browser tab window) and user never gets to interact with the dialog as it disappears after successful page post.
My HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "LsaPage", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //some other fields
    <input type="submit" name="actionType" value="Save" id="btnFormSubmit"/>

<div id="inctivePageDialog" title="This is JQuery dialog">
    <p> Do you wish to terminate LSA Page on Grids?</p>
    <div id="termdatebox">
        <h5>Enter Page termination date.</h5> 
        <input class = "datepicker" id="pageTermDate"/>
        <button type="submit" id="finalize" value="Save">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

And JQuery:

```
$('#btnFormSubmit').click(function (e) { //form submit button

    if (newPageStatus == "I" && pageStatus == "A") { //conditions
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("InactivatePage", "LsaPage")',
            data: { pageId: "@Model.PageID" },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

                var anyActive = 0;

                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    //processing
                    anyActive += 1;
                });

                if (anyActive > 0) {

                    $('#inctivePageDialog').dialog("open"); //open the jquery dialog
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

//dialog that shows up when conditions are met
$('#inctivePageDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    buttons: {
        Yes: function () {
            //if user clicks yes on the dialog, it will ask for the date and show new Save button
            $('#termdatebox').show(); //show input textbox
            $('.ui-button:contains("Yes")').hide(); //hide original dialog Yes button
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

//Save button click event on the dialog 
$('#finalize').on('click', function (e) {

    var termdate = $('#pageTermDate').val();//get user input

    $('#inctivePageDialog').dialog('close');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("InactivatePageRelations", "LsaPage")',
        data: { pageId: "@Model.PageID", termDt: termdate },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put e.PreventDefault() as first line of code in your $('#btnFormSubmit').click(function (e){ ...} ) it will prevent the execution of your form submit event so that you can perform your ajax call and your logic

for more info about the call look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: If conditions are not met inside $('#btnFormSubmit').click, I need to submit the form and with e.preventdefault it does nothing.

Comment: you can submit your form with calling the jquery submit function on your form check here https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: that's what i'm doing inside the dialog save button event. My issue is that, when I dont fire up dialog (conditions not met), I need the form Save button to work as expected and post the form. Currently it fires up in either of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the form via Ajax by yourself. The button type should be `type="button"` which will prevent the form the post back.

```
<button type="button" ...>Save</button>
```

Besides, you should not use **ajax** and **success: ...$('form').submit();** at the same time; it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `<input type="button"` will also do

Comment: @Igor input tag doesn't not allow html, but in this case you can.

Comment: if I make the dialog button type='button', my form still posts after i Save it. 
I also made <input type='button'...> but that would not fire up my form save at all (in that case conditions are not met)

Comment: @AidaM You code will still post, because you have **$('form').submit()** inside **success** call back function. Basically, you post via ajax; when successful, you **again** make the full post back manually. Like I said it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Win I have removed the call to form.submit inside the ajax success, but the page gets posted to controller once the dialog shows up without waiting for ajax calls to get finished.

Comment: @AidaM You need to change the top input to `<input type="button">` too.

Comment: @Win then there is no code to submit the form (if i remove form.submit from ajax and change submit input to button)

Comment: @AidaM You want to make all POST to be ajax. Otherwise, it will be really confusing - some are ajax and some are full post back.